Google apps script to limit access on edit so that only the owner and the one who edited the cell have access
I tried to make a script that on every edit, if the cell is empty everyone has access to edit it. If someone edits it, only that person and the owner can edit it. I have to mention that every user is anonymous, and I can’t get the emails. This script's scope is to limit the access of an edited cell so that users can't modify each other's cells, the first who types in that cells has control over it.
I tried to use a workaround with the protections, but that worked partially, nobody could edit the owner’s cells but everyone could write on top of each other’s cells. Got errors on the trigger for every person except the owner:


Error   Exception: You can't remove yourself as an editor.
    at onEdit(Code:25:14)



This is the code I tried to edit it to make it work. The code was taken from Get the user that changed specific cell by Wim den Herder.
// Test it with colors
// var edittedBackgroundColor = "RED"; // makes the change visible, for test purposes
// var availableBackgroundColor = "LIGHTGREEN"; //  makes the change visible, for test purposes

function onEdit(e) {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toUpperCase().split("");
  var columnStart = e.range.columnStart;
  var rowStart = e.range.rowStart;
  var columnEnd = e.range.columnEnd;
  var rowEnd = e.range.rowEnd;
  var startA1Notation = alphabet[columnStart-1] + rowStart;
  var endA1Notation = alphabet[columnEnd-1] + rowEnd;
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(startA1Notation + ":" + endA1Notation);

  if(range.getValue() === "") {
    Logger.log("Cases in which the entry is empty.");
    if(typeof availableBackgroundColor !== 'undefined' && availableBackgroundColor) 
      range.setBackground(availableBackgroundColor)
    removeEmptyProtections();
    return;
  }

  // Session.getActiveUser() is not accesible in the onEdit trigger
  // The user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger
  // Source: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()

  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Cell ' + startA1Notation + ' is protected');
  if(typeof edittedBackgroundColor !== 'undefined' && edittedBackgroundColor)
    range.setBackground(edittedBackgroundColor);

  // Though neither the owner of the spreadsheet nor the current user can be removed
  // The next line results in only the owner and current user being able to edit

  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  Logger.log("These people can edit now: " + protection.getEditors());

  // Doublecheck for empty protections (if for any reason this was missed before)

  removeEmptyProtections();
}

function removeEmptyProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var protection = protections[i];
    if(! protection.getRange().getValue()) {
      Logger.log("Removes protection from empty field " + protection.getRange().getA1Notation());
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
  return;
}

function isEmptyObject(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify({});
}

This is the scenario I have tested:
PERSON1: edits an empty cell (The cell becomes protected and got the error form the above)
PERSON2: deletes the contents of that cell (The protection is removed and cell is empty, script got no errors)

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show the exact error messages including stack trace from My Executions. Don't paraphrase.

You can replace var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(...) with the simpler const range = e.range); or delete the whole line and simply refer to e.range instead of range.

This is the code I tried to edit it to make it work. The code was taken from Get the user that changed specific cell by Wim den Herder. - I tried the code from this link, and it seems to be working on my end. Aside from @doubleunary's recommendation, it is working. Did you try to edit the code from Wim den Herder? If so, try to paste it as is.

Hello @JatsPPG ! I tested this code on 3 different accounts. One is the owner of the google sheets and 2 accounts are anonymous guests via the share link. The logic for the owner works perfectly. For the other 2, it doesn't seem to work since one can edit on top of each other's cell and this is not intended. And for the code that I edited and tested, it is of no use since I got exactly the same result. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Could you explain how you did it?

I think it is considering anonymous users as one account, which is why they can edit each other's cell. You may try accessing it using a different Google account.

This question is similar to: Get the user that changed specific cell. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
